# For what reason there are 3 bytes more in structs? Can remove?

Tags: c, struct, byte, sizeof

```
struct things {
    char foo[25];
    int bar;
};

struct morethings {
    char morefoo[25];
    int morebar;
    int another;
};

int main() {
    printf("char[25] + int: %d | struct things: %d\n\n", sizeof(char[25]) + sizeof(int), sizeof(struct things));
    printf("char[25] + int + int: %d | struct morethings: %d\n\n", sizeof(char[25]) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int), sizeof(struct morethings));

    return 0;
}
```

Return:

> char[25] + int: 29 | struct things: 32
>
> char[25] + int + int: 33 | struct morethings: 36

I believe that return of `sizeof` should the same in both cases, but the struct always have the most 3 bytes. For what reason this happens?

Can remove? This can disrupt what I'm doing, which is to save in a file structure.

Comment: The reason is padding, and it's related to alignment, you can prevent that with the preprocessor, and in some cases you MUST prevent that.

Comment: 32-bit computers run more efficiently when things like `int`s are nicely aligned on a 4-byte boundary. So the struct makes room for 25 bytes, then throws in 3 of padding, starting the int at byte 28.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question, because I would like to delete these bytes. This could damage what I'm doing, which is to save the structure.

Comment: It depends on which compiler you're using you need `#pragma pack(push) struct Struct {}; #pragma pack(pop)`. Check [*gcc*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html) for example. Or [*MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)

Comment: @KeplerBR I see that there is no solution to prevent padding in the duplicate question. So I reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which compiler you're using, you need something like

```
#pragma pack(push) 
struct things 
  {
    char foo[25];
    int bar;
  };
#pragma pack(pop).
```

Check these links for more information

1. GNU compiler [**gcc**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.htm)
2. Microsoft compiler [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)

There is also a **gcc** specific solution, it is

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) things 
  {
    char foo[25];
    int bar;
  };
```

Comment: I could not solve the problem using your code, more searching, I managed to solve the problem using `#pragma pack(1)`. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to put the largest elements, or those with more strict alignment constraints, first in a structure.  Try:

```
struct things
{
    int bar;
    char foo[25];
};
```

instead of

```
struct things
{
    char foo[25];
    int bar;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Did not work"?  It's not going to change things if you have a "#pragma pack(1)", but try it on non-x86 machine that has really stringent alignment requirements and you will see a difference.

Comment: I deleted the `#pragma` to test your code. I'm using a computer with Windows 8 in 64-bit architecture and using the GCC compiler. Even if I use your code, the structure continues to occupy 32 bytes.